# Delete a project from VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I delete a project in Visual Studio Code?

I've clicked everywhere looking for a solution. I have cleared the recently opened, restarted VS Code but the project doesn't go anywhere. I researched online but there is a void. It seems projects stay there forever!

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to delete the project, you can not delete it from inside the VS Code. you should go to the folder that project is inside that, you can do that with right click on the name of project in toolbar VS Code and select the Reveal the explorer and go directly to the root of the project.

then you can delete the project.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: That's right. You can also right Ctrl+Shift+E, right-click on the project and "Remove project from workspace" if you want to keep the folder on disk but not see it in VS Code.

Comment: Thank you. I do want to keep the folder on the disk. What would I do on a mac?

Answer (score 8):

You would need to use the command pallete and search for

```
Workspaces: Remove Folder from Workspace...
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work. It should be a simple right-click -> delete project

Answer (score 5):

'File' >> 'Close Folder' removes the project from the explorer sidebar without actually deleting from the disk.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Close Workspace' from command pallete, this will close the workspace from VS Code keeping all the files on the disk.

[Close project in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNCf9.png)